# Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to run abb_exec. Error: closed adb: connect error for write: closed

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator, expo

Getting this error while trying to run react-native app on emulator through expo.

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: adb: failed to run abb_exec. 
Error: closed adb: connect error for write: closed
```

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using linux or mac os cob, run the following command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project_name
after that rm -rm node_modules /
then npm i
```

and run react native again